# Laravel Vue — router-view not rendering

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So i'm trying to learn about SPA by building one with laravel vue vue-router and vuex.

my problem is that router-view is not rendering at all no matter what i do and i'm starting to lose hope in here, and it displays Hello message from vue components only.

the code as long as i know don't have any errors.

this is my setup and files

laravel router page: web.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\AppController::class, 'index'])->where('any', '.*');
```

home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <App></App>
@endsection
```

and this is my vue files

app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';            
import router from './router'     
import App from './components/App'
                                  
require('./bootstrap');           
                                  
const app = new Vue({             
 el: '#app',                   
 components: { App },          
 router                        
});
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'                                       
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'                          
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent'
                                                            
Vue.use( VueRouter )                                        
                                                            
export default new VueRouter( {                             
 mode: 'history',                                          
 router: [                                                 
  { path: '/', component: ExampleComponent }              
 ]                                                         
} )
```

App.vue file

```
<template>
 <div class="content">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <router-view></router-view>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'App'
 }
</script>
```

ExampleComponenet.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
  <h1>This is the Example Component</h1>
 </div>
</template>
```

the **OUT PUT** that i got is the App.vue component loads but `<router-view></router-view>` render as html comment `<!---->`

```
Hello
<!---->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried recreating your code in codesandbox and it turns out you're defining your routes wrong. Instead of `router` you have to use `routes` on your `router.js`

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-leftpad-fwtf7?file=/src/router.js

---

In your `app.js` you're telling Vue app to mount on an element with an id of `app` thus the

```
{
  el: "#app",
  components: ...
}
```

but on your `home.blade.php` you dont have any `<div id="app"></div>`.

It could be that it exists on your `layouts.app` but you didn't include it. If it's not there, then that's the problem.

I'm not also sure about how you declared your route in Laravel:

```
Route::get('/{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\AppController::class, 'index'])->where('any', '.*');
```

Usually it'd look like:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Source: https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel

Comment: i'm using <App></App> tags and the its renders App.vue Hello message but it won't render the <router-view></router-view>.

Comment: Also about the Laravel Route i'm using the news syntax that is in Laravel 8.

Comment: where should i import it ? in which file

Comment: Thank you man 

i have used `router` instead of `routes` in router.js file. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, please try this.

```
 router: [                                                 
  { path: '/example', component: ExampleComponent }              
 ]
```

then visit URL "http://localhost/exmaple" and see if it works correctly.

Comment: For my case because i'm using in web.php file ```Route::get('/{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\AppController::class, 'index'])->where('any', '.*');```

it will show the page in / path only.

Comment: Okay, he is right.
el: "#app" is correct. 
I hope you are doing well.